# Wait for multiple reactions Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my Goal is to make a little "roulette" game. Every member who want to play should be able to react to any emoji. But it seems that my code only detects the first reaction. I want to get a list which member reacted to which emoji to work with it later in code. But the goal for now is it to run my IF statement for every Reaction. Hope you can understand what I want^^

```
@commands.command()
async def roulette(self, ctx, value: int):
    msg = await ctx.send(f"Choose a color. Make sure you have at least {value} Kakera in your wallet!")
    await msg.add_reaction("⚫")
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["⚫", "", ""]

    try:

        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)

        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        async for user in reaction.users():
            await ctx.send('{0} has reacted with {1.emoji}!'.format(user, reaction))
        print()
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⚫":
            await ctx.send(f"Black from {user}!")
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await ctx.send(f"Red from {user}!")
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await ctx.send(f"Green from {user}!")
        else:
            print("Unknown reaction")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Abort execution!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.bot.wait_for` [returns the first event that matches the criteria](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for). After one user clicks one reaction, the bot moves on past this section of code and your bot will not respond to other people.

You'll need to keep waiting for new reactions, until you receive that `TimeoutError` or some other criteria. You can use a loop or a different event such as [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add).

Comment: Thank you very much! Will go with on_reaction_add event^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try, within the command:

```
@commands.command()
async def roulette(self, ctx, value: int):
    ...
    
    @bot.event()
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
        # your logic here
```